# Connection refused with ElasticSearch on Digital Ocean

Tags: elasticsearch, digital-ocean

I install Elastic Search using this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-16-04) changing only version by Elastic Search.

Set `network.host: 127.0.0.1` to access by terminal. But show this error when try connect:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your port 9200 is open or not, then check if you're not using the `UFW` `firewall`.

In case of you are using the `UFW firewall` :

- `sudo ufw allow 9200`